# Postgres aws_s3 extention not accepting timestamp input

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-extensions

I have a csv with a timestamp column like this `2021-05-27 11:57:23` but the `table_import_from_s3` function (from the aws_s3 postgres extension) keeps giving me this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "start_time"
```

Has anyone successfully imported timestamp fields using this extension?

A manual `INSERT` statement with the same values works fine.

Comment: It looks like the issue is how the `aws_s3` extension is reading the CSV, because `start_time` is a column header, not a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the missing `HEADER` parameter which gets passed to the postgres `COPY` command in the extension, since my CSV file **does** contain a header row.

#### Before

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 (
  'my-table',
  '',
  '(format csv)',
  :'s3_uri'
);
```

#### After

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 (
  'my-table',
  '',
  '(format csv, header)',
  :'s3_uri'
);
```